# Hyper-V - backup guest VM (while powered down) just by copying files?

Tags: hyper-v

If you have a guest Windows 2008 VM in Hyper-V what is the simplest way to make a backup of it in its entirety.

I'm happy to power the guest VM down before making the backup. The disks used by the VM are all in one directory.

Is there any reason I can't just use xcopy while the VM is powered down ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can, depending on the host version (which you didn't specify.)  But you'll get mostly the same result with a little bit more determinism in the restore process if you export the VM instead.  This will copy the files and generalize the configuration somewhat, storing the config in a form that can be more easily imported later.